# How could I loop through this json object in php file?

Tags: php, json, loops, decode

I have converted an xml object returned from a php function into json format to send it to js file like.

```
function searchResults($q) { ...
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
    return json_encode($xml); }
```

I receive/use it in js like

```
  var msg_top = "<"+"?php echo searchResults('windows');"+"?"+">";
```

Then I receive it back in php & decoded.

```
      $json = $_POST['msg_top'];
      $msg = json_decode($json);
```

Now how do I loop through it to get all values of its certain properties that I could have get from xml object(which I converted into json). This is how I loop over xml object to get all values of its certain properties:

```
   foreach ($xml->entry as $status) {
   echo $status->author->name.''.$status->content);
   }
```

How do I get all those values from decoded json object $msg?
**EDITED**
I tried in same HTML where I am using js to receive & POST php search function data via ajax, I tried following code to loop through json in php. But it did not show anything.

```
$obj = searchResults(testword);//serach function returns json encoded data
$obj = json_decode($obj, true);
$count = count($obj);  
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
echo $obj[$i][content];}// using xml for it, I get ouput like foreach ($xml3->entry as 
                       // $status) {status->content}
```

Comment: are you actually trying to execute php from js? nice idea, but will not work...

Comment: @joni, thanX for the reply. May be something in my post confuses u. Not really, I just need to access some php results in js, use those there & send back again to php server for further use.

Comment: but how does `"<"+"?php echo searchResults('windows');"+"?"+">"` get executed on PHP runtime??

Comment: Is it not like that whenever this function is called, it will return results? As my need is to get results in js that this php function returns. So I am calling it using php tags in js

Comment: you cannot call a php func from js, except using ajax. And please use a @joni if you answer to me, so I get notified =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, `json_decode` returns an stdClass. stdClass-es can be used the same way as associative arrays with `foreach`.

Alternatively, you can ask `json_decode` to return an associative array:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['foo'], TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `$msg` for the FOR LOOP as it is the array.

Try to see what it hold using this

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($msg)."</pre";
//And if you see the correct array structure
foreach($msg as $key=>$value) {
  //do your things
}
```

Comment: I am just saying this as `$status` is used in FOR LOOP